# how to replace src domian tld

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to change tld in image src and background image of div
as in this example:

from

```
<div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; background-image: url(https://ap.domain.com/image.aspx?id=19393262&amp;x=2&amp;y=1); background-size: cover; background-repeat: no-repeat; border-radius: 0px;"></div>
```

to

```
<div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; background-image: url(https://new.domain.org/image.aspx?id=19393262&amp;x=2&amp;y=1); background-size: cover; background-repeat: no-repeat; border-radius: 0px;"></div>
```

and from

```
<img id="dynamic" class="expand" src="https://ap.domain.com/imgx.aspx?id=5742757&amp;type=newsHi">
```

to

```
<img id="dynamic" class="expand" src="https://new.domain.org/imgx.aspx?id=5742757&amp;type=newsHi">
```

Comment: static or dynamic elements? I mean do you know what are all the elements that have the property?

Answer (score 2):

Use this code to change src of image.

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('img')).forEach(x => {
  x.src = x.src.replace(/ap.domain.com/,'new.domain.org')
  console.log(x);
});
```

This will iterate through all image tags and change their src.

To change background-image of div, use the below code.

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('div')).forEach(x => {
  x.style.backgroundImage = x.style.backgroundImage.replace(/ap.domain.com/,'new.domain.org')
  console.log(x);
});
```

```js
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('div')).forEach(x => {
  x.style.backgroundImage = x.style.backgroundImage.replace(/ap.domain.com/,'new.domain.org')
  console.log(x);
});

Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('img')).forEach(x => {
  x.src = x.src.replace(/ap.domain.com/,'new.domain.org')
  console.log(x);
});
```

```html
<div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; background-image: url(https://ap.domain.com/image.aspx?id=19393262&amp;x=2&amp;y=1); background-size: cover; background-repeat: no-repeat; border-radius: 0px;"></div>
<div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; background-image: url(https://ap.domain.com/image.aspx?id=19334262&amp;x=2&amp;y=1); background-size: cover; background-repeat: no-repeat; border-radius: 0px;"></div>
<div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; background-image: url(https://ap.domain.com/image.aspx?id=19234262&amp;x=2&amp;y=1); background-size: cover; background-repeat: no-repeat; border-radius: 0px;"></div>
<div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; background-image: url(https://ap.domain.com/image.aspx?id=19121262&amp;x=2&amp;y=1); background-size: cover; background-repeat: no-repeat; border-radius: 0px;"></div>
<div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; background-image: url(https://ap.domain.com/image.aspx?id=11293262&amp;x=2&amp;y=1); background-size: cover; background-repeat: no-repeat; border-radius: 0px;"></div>
<img id="dynamic" class="expand" src="https://ap.domain.com/imgx.aspx?id=5337&amp;type=newsHi">

<img id="dynamic" class="expand" src="https://ap.domain.com/imgx.aspx?id=512&amp;type=newsHi">

<img id="dynamic" class="expand" src="https://ap.domain.com/imgx.aspx?id=57412757&amp;type=newsHi">

<img id="dynamic" class="expand" src="https://ap.domain.com/imgx.aspx?id=5741212757&amp;type=newsHi">
```

Comment: The domain should also change from `.com` to `.org`.

Comment: noted. Thanks. @DaniloKörber I've been editing your answer to make it work using `$.each`. Don't know why you deleted it

Comment: Because your answer is better than mine was... :-)